# Is C# interpreted or compiled?

Tags: c#

I thought that C# generated compiled code (by JIT), but I have lately discovered that I can  edit code while debugging mode in C# (VS 2008). Does that mean that C# is interpreted?

Comment: You could edit code while debugging with the Visual C++ 6.0 compiler/IDE in certain circumstances and C++ is fully compiled. It all depends on what the actual code is.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Betamoo - it's nearly 10 years since I used VC++ 6.0, I can't remember the specifics. Check out the Edit and Continue link @Brian supplied in his comment on @Greg Hewgill's answer.

Comment: You haven't tried running on 64bit Windows then? "Edit and continue" is ... discontinued. As an aside, I always found edit&continue to be a bit like programming in quicksand and mainly pointless. I don't miss it.

Comment: @spender: Not correct (at least for .NET). Though you won't be able to use it with the 64-bit CLR: http://blogs.msdn.com/stevejs/archive/2005/11/15/493018.aspx

Comment: I wouldn't have needed 64Bit Windows except to use the 64bit CLR (particularly the "more memory" bit), so I didn't know that.

Comment: Related post - [Is C# partially interpreted or really compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8837329/465053) & [If C# is not interpreted, then why is a VM needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9556354/465053)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a trick. The C# compiler/debugger/IDE is just smart and can compile code on the fly while you're debugging.

Comment: It's called "Edit and Continue" or "EnC" for short: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c(VS.100).aspx

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

Answer (score 7):

C# is compiled to IL which is then JIT'ed at runtime into instructions specific to the processor the program is running on.

Editing code while debugging C# is a feature of VS2008 which more than likely compiling any changes in the background