# Difference between JVM and HotSpot?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

What exactly is HotSpot and how does it relate to JVM and OpenJDK? Is it a library? What exactly does it do?

Also, what is the difference between OpenJDK and HotSpot?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

The definition of what exactly is a Java Virtual Machine is stated in the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/)

The JVM is by definition a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Machine), i.e. a software machine that simulates what a real machine does. Like a real machine, it has an [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), a virtual computer architecture and an execution model. It is capable of running code written with this virtual instruction set, pretty much like a real machine can run machine code.

[HotSpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) is an implementation of the JVM concept. It was originally developed by Sun, and now it is owned by Oracle. There are other implementations of the JVM specification, like [JRockit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit), [IBM J9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_J9), among many others.

See [List of Java Virtual Machine Implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)

The [OpenJDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is a project under which an open source implementation of HotSpot (and many other pieces of the JDK  e.g. compiler, APIs, tools, etc) is developed.

Answer (score 87):

Note: *AdoptOpenJDK* has changed its name to *Adoptium* after moving to the Eclipse Foundation in late 2020-06.

---

> Difference between JVM and HotSpot?

A [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) is an imaginary computer that has never been physically built as hardware. A JVM runs programs compiled to its imaginary [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) written to storage as an [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) known as [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).

At runtime, the bytecode must be translated from the imaginary instruction set to the actual instruction set of the CPU of the host machine. This can be done on-the-fly by an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)). Or the bytecode can be fully [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and [cached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Software_caches), to run faster than through the interpreter, in a process known as [Just-In-Time (JIT) compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation).

Over the decades, there have been many [implementations of the JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines). Most have fallen away.

[*HotSpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) is one implementation of JIT technology that starts by running interpreted, and watches the actual performance of the app. Parts of the app are then selected to be fully-compiled as native code and cached, for much faster execution. HotSpot was developed at [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) as a commercial product. After acquiring Sun, [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) further evolved HotSpot by combining important parts of their competing product, [*JRockit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit).  HotSpot is now open-sourced through the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project, available free-of-charge.

Another such implementation in [*OpenJ9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9), developed by [IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM), and now open-sourced through the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation) and available free-of-charge. Some JVM distributions built on OpenJDK replace  HotSpot with OpenJ9 while still using the rest of OpenJDK such as the [Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition) class libraries. For example, the pre-built distributions available at [*AdoptOpenJDK*](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) provide your choice of *HotSpot* or *OpenJ9* on some hardware.

Diagram showing history of HotSpot & JRockit merging, and OpenJ9 both available in AdoptOpenJDK.

[image: Diagram showing history of HotSpot & JRockit merging, and OpenJ9 both available in AdoptOpenJDK]

> What exactly is HotSpot and how does it relate to JVM and OpenJDK? Is it a library? What exactly does it do?

- [*HotSpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) is an implementation of the part of a JVM that interprets and/or compiles Java bytecode to be executed on the host CPU.
- [*OpenJ9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) is an alternative.

*OpenJ9* is generally known for much faster starting and much lower memory usage initially, while *HotSpot* may run more efficiently overall for long-running apps. Both are well-regarded, well-worn, and available with distributions of OpenJDK.

[*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is an open-source project that fully implements the [Java Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), [JSR](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/overview)s, and [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0)s that define [the Java platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)). Major contributors include Oracle, IBM, Apple, and others.

Every JVM implementation I know of today is based entirely or mostly on the OpenJDK [codebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codebase) and uses either HotSpot or OpenJ9 technology.

Besides the JVM, OpenJDK also provides an implementation in source code for all classes required by the Java SE specifications, such as *java.lang*, *java.util*, *java.time*, and other packages.

> Also, what is the difference between OpenJDK and HotSpot?

The source code for *HotSpot* is housed, maintained, and further developed as part of the *OpenJDK* project. The alternative, *OpenJ9*, is housed, maintained, and further developed at the *Eclipse Foundation*, while replacing HotSpot in some distributions of OpenJDK.

Some distributions of Java technology choose to ship with HotSpot. Some distributions choose to substitute the portion of the *OpenJDK* codebase that is *HotSpot* with the alternative, *OpenJ9*.

Here is a flow chart graphic to help you choose a vendor for a distribution of the Java platform.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

Comment: Very helpful  answer .Thanks sir

Comment: Man, now I wish all answers on SO were this detailed

Answer (score 33):

**OpenJDK** (Open Java Development Kit) is a free and open source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE).The openjdk is a project started by Sun Microsystems, nowadays care by many companies and the community for build a Java Development Kit absolutely in open source. As per the [official documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/community/opensourcejdk-jsp-136417.html).

*OpenJDK is an open-source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE) specifications. In May 2007, Sun released a fully buildable Java Development Kit (JDK) version for Java SE to the OpenJDK Community as free software under the GNU General Public License version two (GPLv2). Sun announced the Interim Governing Board for the OpenJDK community. Sun also announced that OpenJDK-based implementations can use the Java SE 6 Technical Compatibility Kit (JCK) to establish compatibility with the Java SE 6 specification.*

The **OpenJDK project** consists of a number of components - **HotSpot (the virtual machine)**, the Java Class Library and the javac Java compiler.For more on it, visit its [site](http://openjdk.java.net/).

The current JVM provided by Sun/Oracle is called **HotSpot** because it seeks hot spots of use in the code (places where code is more intensively used) for "just-in-time" optimization. From the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot), *HotSpot, released as the "Java HotSpot Performance Engine" is a Java virtual machine for desktops and servers, maintained and distributed by Oracle Corporation.*

Comment: I heard OpenJDK also uses HotSpot to execute code? Is that true?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot, so you are saying HotSpot is part of OpenJDK? Or is there also a proprietary HotSpot as the answer above suggests?

Comment: @NINC, So Hotspot is both part of OracleJDK and OpenJDK? Hotspot = JRockit = OracleJDK = OpenJDK?

Answer (score 9):

HotSpot is, as mentioned above, a cross-platform implementation of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) Concept, and is distributed with the OpenJDK (Java Developer Kit), under the GNU General Public License. HotSpot is written mainly in C++, and was originally developed under Sun Microsystems. It is currently developed under the OpenJDK Project, at www.java.net. The HotSpot JVM was available as an add-on for Java 1.2, and later was used as the default Sun JVM in Java 1.3. The JVM is currently in Version 7, Build b147, and has an active development community behind it.

For more information, goto:
https://www.java.net/

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 8):

> JVM is an abstract machine (specifications). HotSpot, OpenJDK and JRockit and so are implementations of JVM.

**Free and open source implementations**

- **HotSpot**, the primary reference Java VM implementation
- **OpenJDK** — Open Java Development Kit is a free and open source implementation licensed under the GNU General Public License (GNU
  GPL) with a linking exception.

**Proprietary implementations**

- **JRockit** (originally from Appeal Virtual Machines) acquired by Oracle for Linux, Windows and Solaris

for more [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)
[link](http://www.dbi-services.com/index.php/blog/entry/a-comparison-of-java-virtual-machines-hotspot-jvm-vs-jrockit-jvm) explains differences between HotSpot and JRocket