# Where to download Hotspot JVM? Different from Oracle's JVM?

Tags: jvm, jvm-hotspot

I read a few posts about JVM at Stack Overflow and would like to download a binary copy of the Hotspot JVM, yet I am not able to find it on http://www.java.net.

Beside that, what is the difference between Hotspot JVM and JVMs found at [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Is Oracle JVM good for a production website?

Comment: HotSpot JVM is a part of both Oracle JDK and OpenJDK. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568253/difference-between-jvm-and-hotspot

Comment: apangin, are you saying that when I download Oracle's JVM from the above I gave, I get Hotspot automatically? Thanks!

Comment: You download JDK, not JVM, but yes - it has HotSpot JVM inside.

Comment: apangin, thanks for your follow-up! Voted up your responses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Overview:**

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568253/difference-between-jvm-and-hotspot) may clear up your questions regarding "What is JVM, Hotspot and OpenJDK".

Basically:

[JVM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine) means *Java Virtual Machine*. The JVM is the underlying runtime that executes java bytecode. There are multiple different implementations out there, all implementing the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/)

HotSpot is the most used implementation of the JVM concept. It is used in both, Oracle JDK and OpenJDK. Oracle's JDK can be downloaded on oracle's website, currently http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. This is "the typical JVM you will find on a normal user's windows machine".

[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/) is the open source project maintaining and impelmenting the HotSpot JVM, but also many other projects beside the JVM such as [Graal](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/graal) or [VisualVM](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/visualvm/). On Ubuntu for example you can install this OpenJDK (current version 8) by running `sudo apt-get install openjdk8`.

**Conclusion:**

While this explaination is not really perfect, it may be good enough to understand that there is no big difference between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK. If you are interested in a little more info on this, have a look at the SO question [Differences between Oracle JDK and Open JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection)

---

**JDK / JVM sourcecode:**

If you are interested in the source code, OpenJDK is the way to go. [Here you can find](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/) the current OpenJDK 8 (which includes the HotSpot JVM). Its source code can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u). It also states how to download the source code:

> The jdk8u-dev forest for ongoing development can be cloned using this command: hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev;cd jdk8u-dev;sh get_source.sh .
>
> The corresponding master forest jdk8u can be cloned using this command: hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u;cd jdk8u;sh get_source.sh .
>
> In addition, the source code for the last release, 8u66, is available by cloning the 8u master forest : http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u and using the 'jdk8u66-b17' mercurial tag.

Comment: Markus, thanks for your detailed answer. It is crystal-clear. I would like to have a binary copy of OpenJDK 8 to run a Spring web application on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. I am not able to find it at openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u you mentioned. Where to get it? Many thanks!

Comment: As stated on http://openjdk.java.net/: `If you came here looking for Oracle JDK 8 product binaries for Solaris, Linux, Mac OS X, or Windows, which are based largely on the same code, you can download them from java.oracle.com.`. So even OpenJDK states to go with the oracle downloads on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html if you are looking for Windows binaries as I wrote in my answer. :)
I'll be happy if you accept this as answer if I could help you :)