# install Java on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java

I'm installing Java on Ubuntu 15.10
when I typed `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
The result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/xenial
```

How to fix it? thank you

Comment: it seems to be that it searches for packages for Xenial Xerus, Ubuntu 16.04 which is Alpha while I write this comment. Do you maybe know why it might think that you are running on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` if OpenJDK also meets your needs (and most probably it will if you aks about "installing Java")

For OpenJDK 8, you should then be able to find your Java executable in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Comment: It notified "Unable to locate package openjdk8"

Comment: @GaussShiroemonMadeon: Try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`, I updated the answer. Otherwise, just tpye `sudo apt-get install openjdk` and hit "Tabulator", then apt-get will show you all possible packages.

Comment: thank you. I tried. and the result: 
openjdk-8-jdk is already the newest version (8u72-b15-2ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1438 not upgraded

Comment: @GaussShiroemonMadeon: Then just look into `/usr/lib/jvm/` and you should find your JVM(s) installed. My _java_ executable is located at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Comment: Me too. my java executable is located at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

Comment: @GaussShiroemonMadeon: So, is your problem fixed? If so, you can use the tick mark to accept this as an answer.

Comment: i don't know. when I typed sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java it was failed

Comment: @GaussShiroemonMadeon: If you have OpenJDK installed (as we just made sure), why do you still want to use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`? Is there a special reason for this? You _already have_ Java installed, the OpenJDK version, not the Oracle version. There is nearly no difference between those two, if you want to have more info on the difference, [have a look at this answer explaining it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508612/where-to-download-hotspot-jvm-different-from-oracles-jvm/35513000#35513000)

Answer (score 0):

Why You Going Trough The Hard Way ? .
 
Just Open Ubuntu Software Center And Search For **JDK** And Click On Install Button . So Easy 
check your **sources.list** file in **/etc/apt/sources.list** and make sure the file is not changed or broken .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that PPA doesn't have anything for Ubuntu 15.10.

I use [java-package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/java-package) to convert the tarball from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to a .deb package.

*PS. this question is better suited for [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to check if you are behind a proxy??

So you need to set the https_proxy environmental variable to your custom setting, for example:

export https_proxy=http://myproxy.domain.net:8080/

after that, you can run the commnad "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java"

I don't know why the add-apt-repository doesn't use the proxy settings for apt.

Comment: You can use this command  
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 0):

Open Applicaction -> Accessories -> Terminal

Type in the command line as below:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Type in the command line as below:

```
apt-cache search jdk
```

(Note: openjdk-8-jdk is symbolically used here. You can choose the JDK version as per your requirement.)

For "JAVA_HOME" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
```

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration. You should use your path as per your installation.)

For "PATH" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin
```

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demonstration. You should use your path as per your installation.)

Check for "open jdk" installation, just type command in "Terminal" as shown below:

```
javac -version
```