# Openjdk and Java webstart

Tags: java

Do the latest open jdk retain support for Java webstart?

When building a Java program using openjdk in eclipse can it run on systems thay have regular oracle jre installed?

I'm curious because I want to try and start using openjdk (newer versions 12 maybe) if it still has JWS. But if a client installs oracle jre 12 will they be able to run webstart via my app build with openjre? I ask because we really can't count on a client pc having a non oracle jre installed.

Comment: Then what benefit is it to use openjdk over oracle?

Comment: Related: [*What is the reason to use OpenJDK?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47236543/642706)

Comment: Related: [*OpenJDK vs Java HotspotVM*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44335605/642706)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Q: Do the latest OpenJDK retain support for Java WebStart?

No.  Not Oracle JDK.  Not OpenJDK.  Not (AFAIK) any other Java implementations based on the latest OpenJDK sources.

- WebStart support was deprecated in Oracle JDK / JRE distros with Java 9 and removed in Java 11.
- According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK), OpenJDK *has never included WebStart*.  It was Oracle JDK/JRE specific.

There is now a replacement for classic [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) in the form of [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/).  (The OpenWebStart 1.0.0 release was announced on Nov 18th 2019.)

The other alternative is to move away from Java WebStart / JNLP to an alternative such as building platform-specific executables using jlink and distributing them in some other way.

Read [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf), a white paper from Oracle, update 2020-05.

---

> Q: When building a Java program using OpenJDK in Eclipse can it run on systems that have regular Oracle JRE installed?

Yes, provided that the version of Java installed is new enough.  But note that Oracle stopped releasing JRE releases after Java 8.  It is now only JDKs if you are using an Oracle Java release, or an OpenJDK build from the OpenJDK download site.

---

> Q: Then what benefit is it to use OpenJDK over Oracle?

See the following:

- [What is the reason to use OpenJDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236543)
- [OpenJDK vs Java HotspotVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335605)

Note that there are other alternatives.  Read ["Java is Still Free"](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244).

---

> I ask because we can't count on a client PC having a non Oracle JRE installed.

Then you should be looking at `jlink`.  It creates self-contained executables.  That means that you don't depend on having *any* JRE installed on the client PC.

Comment: Awesome!! OpenWebStart

Comment: You can used icedTea for it with an arbitrary JRE https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/428601/25085

Comment: Quite useful for the oracle swing tutorials. They offer their examples only with webstart. Thanks for OpenWebStart!

Answer (score 8):

Several parties (RedHat, AdoptOpenJDK & Karakun) are currently working on an open source replacement of Oracle WebStart. The repo can be found at [karakun/OpenWebStart](https://github.com/karakun/OpenWebStart). You can find additional information about the project on [openwebstart.com](https://openwebstart.com/).