# Could not find artifact javax.jnlp:jnlp-api:jar:5.0 at specified path

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, slick2d

I add the slick2d dependency to my pom.xml file but it highlights an error in red saying `Could not find artifact javax.jnlp:jnlp-api:jar:5.0 at specified path` at the top of the file where it says:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Even after running the test command in vscode it still gives a similar error: `Could not resolve dependencies for project com.github.shia5347.universalelement:UniversalElement:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.jnlp:jnlp-api:jar:5.0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar`.

Here is my pom.xml in case needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.github.shia5347.universalelement</groupId>
  <artifactId>UniversalElement</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>UniversalElement</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slick2d/slick2d-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slick2d</groupId>
    <artifactId>slick2d-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am using linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to resolve your issue is to use Oracle JDK.

From slick2d site at https://github.com/nguillaumin/slick2d-maven:

- Slick 2D depends on javaws.jar which ships with the Oracle JDK (It's not available in the public Maven repositories). The pom.xml file references a local filesystem path to javaws.jar for that reason.
- It won't work with OpenJDK for the reason above (Can be solved by providing javaws.jar separately). On some Linux distributions, you can install Netx and change the system path to point to netx.jar. For example on Ubuntu the package to install is icedtea-netx-common and the jar is in /usr/share/icedtea-web/netx.jar

See also this link [Openjdk and Java webstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930547/openjdk-and-java-webstart)

Answer (score 2):

Since I dont like to be limited to Oracle JDK, I use the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slick2d</groupId>
    <artifactId>slick2d-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jnlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnlp-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This will tell maven to skip the jnlp-api module.
It will also allow me to use AdoptOpenJDK with slick2d.