# Download OpenJDK Java 11.0.11+9 from Oracle without using a third-party vendor

Tags: java, java-11

### Short Description:

I'd like to get the GPL2-CPE licensed version of the JavaJDK, which I will call "OpenJDK", as I prefer that license to Oracle's restrictive OTN license. The snag is that I want the 11.0.11+9 Windows ZIP version, which [this Oracle page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-11-relnotes.html) and [Eclipse Adoptium / AdoptOpenJDK page](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html) both list as the most recent version, *without* going to Adoption. I want the Oracle version "straight from the horse's mouth," so to speak, to avoid any discrepancies between the documentation I was quickly able to download from Oracle and the JDK I have installed. I was able to easily get the OpenJDK 16.0.1 ZIP from jdk.java.net but not OpenJDK 11.0.11+9. During my process of attempting to get OpenJDK 11.0.11+9, I have come with various additional questions I'd like answered.

### Long Description

**What I've tried:**

I: The following loop:

1. I started at [this Oracle page,](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) which contains the OTN-licensed JDK, and saw the advertisement for OpenJDK: "End users and developers looking for free JDK versions: Oracle OpenJDK offers the same features and performance as Oracle JDK under the GPL license ."
2. On jdk.java.net I see the "Ready for Use" section has JDK 16, which I don't want. I click on the only entry for JDK 11 I see, which is under "[Reference Implementations](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11)." I download that file, and the ZIP has the name "OpenJDK-11+28_windows-x64_bin.zip" which sounds like an older version of JDK 11. So on the Reference Implementations page, I read, "Production-ready binaries under the GPL are available from Oracle; and will be in most popular Linux distributions."
3. I am led to [this page](https://jdk.java.net/11/) which states, "The JDK 11 Early Access Program has concluded. Please visit Java SE Downloads for production-ready builds."
4. I visit the page linked under "Java SE Downloads" and am taken back to the page in step 1.

II: While writing this question, a suggested question was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335605/openjdk-vs-java-hotspotvm). An answer on that page had several diagrams that helped explain a lot of things, but the diagrams again redirect me to either jdk.java.net or third-party vendors.

III: [This page](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) has an old version of OpenJDK 11.

IV: On [this page](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/), the text "General Availability" is not a link.

### Questions what I've done raises:

1. How can I get Oracle OpenJDK 11.0.11+9 directly from Oracle?
2. Does the version available at Adoptium have *any* differences to Oracle OpenJDK 11.0.11+9 from Oracle?
3. If getting what I'm looking for is impossible, where does Adoptium get what they provide? Do they just build their builds from the source?
4. If what I'm looking for is not possible, *why* is it not possible? Is it due to Oracle's licensing decisions? Does the update I'm looking for the count as a paid support patch? If so, I thought Oracle didn't release those updates to OpenJDK?

### Disclaimer:

If this is a stupid/repeated question, I sincerely apologize. I hate being a pest, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: The official [downloads page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) has what you are looking for, you can select the [version 11 releases section](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) which has 11.0.11+9 as the given download. See here also on the OpenJDK site with a link to the above, and is likely that bit that threw you, the bit you wanted was the link related to "Please visit Java SE Downloads for production ready builds": http://jdk.java.net/11/

Comment: @sorifiend If you follow [the link you gave me] (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) and click on the entry for "Windows x64 Compressed Archive", before downloading you are prompted "I reviewed and accept the Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE." This is the restrictive licensing agreement I don't want to use unless it is impossible to get this same archive under GPL2 w/ CPE. Not trying to offend you, but this isn't an answer. Unless I'm still misunderstanding?

Comment: It's a good question, but you ask "How can I get Oracle OpenJDK 11.0.11+9 directly from Oracle", but you also state "I'd like to get the GPL2-CPE licensed version", but to my understanding, you can't have both of those things. Either grab your JDK from Oracle with an oracle license, or get the GPL2-CPE version from another source for example the [Adopt OpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/), or similar. To answer question 3, yes they do; and question 4, why would oracle publish a free version on their website while also trying to sell/license it for commercial use on the same site?

Comment: @sorifiend I believe your are conflating *Oracle JDK*, their commercial product, with *Oracle OpenJDK*, their GPL2-CPE licensed product. So the first sentence of your comment is incorrect. To be fair, Oracle has been very sloppy with the naming and marketing. The [product page](https://jdk.java.net/) for *Oracle OpenJDK* does not even show an official product name! Yet the counterpart page for [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) does mention the other product's name. Very confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

[*Oracle OpenJDK*](https://jdk.java.net/), not to be confused with [*Oracle JDK*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html). For [Java 11 specifically](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11).

But just as good are implementations of Java provided by:

- *Azul Platform Core* & *Azul Platform Prime* by Azul Systems (formerly *Zulu* and *Zing*)
- *Red Hat build of OpenJDK* by Red Hat (IBM)
- *Coretto* by Amazon
- *Microsoft Build of OpenJDK* by Microsoft
- *Adoptium* by the Eclipse Foundation (formerly *AdoptOpenJDK*)
- *Pivotal Distribution of OpenJDK* by Pivotal Software, Inc.
- *SapMachine* by SAP
- *Liberica* by BellSoft
- Source and builds via *Ports & Packages* on FreeBSD
- Source and builds via *aptget* and such on Linux

## Details

> If this is a stupid/repeated question, I sincerely apologize. I hate being a pest, but I can't figure this out.

While not stupid, yes, this is a repeated question. You made some specific points, so I will respond specifically. But I will *try* to be brief. For more detail, search Stack Overflow for many existing such questions.

> the GPL2-CPE licensed version of the JavaJDK, which I will call "OpenJDK"

You misunderstand the nature of how the Java ecosystem works.

[*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is not a product. OpenJDK is an open-source project based on an industry-wide collaboration. The principal goal of the project is producing a codebase implementing the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), along with [JDK Enhancement Proposals (JEPs)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0) and [Java Specification Requests (JSRs)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/overview). You can view and obtain the source code [via Mercurial](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/) or [via GitHub.com](https://github.com/openjdk).

OpenJDK is owned by [Oracle Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) but operated in tandem with several collaborating companies including IBM/Red Hat, Apple, SAP, and others who contribute talent and code.

The OpenJDK project does *not* produce binaries of the final released versions. Instead, several vendors release binaries and/or installers for the official releases. Most of these vendors’ products are based largely or entirely on the OpenJDK source code. Oracle and other organizations provide suites of tests to verify that such products comply with the Java specs. Note that to use the Java™ legally-protected trademark, a company must come to term with Oracle. In contrast, the *OpenJDK* term can be used freely by any vendor, so you will see that term in many of the products.

> I want the Oracle version "straight from the horse's mouth,"

There is nothing special about getting a Java implementation from Oracle in particular.

Oracle has repeatedly publicly officially, in writing and verbally, stated that their own Oracle-branded *Oracle JDK*/*Oracle Java SE* product (requiring a fee for use in production) will be maintained at feature-parity with the OpenJDK project. Oracle even went so far as to donate some related formerly-commercial products such as *Flight Recorder* and *Mission Control* to the OpenJDK project.

Oracle retains the right to distribute fixes to their paying customers on an urgent basis. But otherwise Oracle contributes to, and depends on, the OpenJDK code base.

> … to avoid any discrepancies between the documentation I was quickly able to download from Oracle

All vendors producing products implementing the Java specs depend on that very same documentation.

> An answer on that page had several diagrams that were helpful in explaining a lot of things

Thanks, [those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56247705/642706) are my handiwork.

> but the diagrams again redirects me to either jdk.java.net or third-party vendors

➥ Oracle produces *three* products implementing the Java specs:

- [*Oracle JDK*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) — Their commercially-supported binaries. Fee required for use in production (see Oracle’s license terms).
- [*Oracle OpenJDK*](https://jdk.java.net/) — Oracle's build of the OpenJDK codebase, GPL2-CPE licensed, free-of-cost. To quote Oracle: “offers the same features and performance as Oracle JDK under the GPL license”.
- [*GraalVM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM) — A special product offering features like ahead-of-time native compilation.

These three Oracle products are shown in [my flowchart diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k5u8.png) as the first three green bubbles. One green bubble is the first in the higher group of "special needs" products, for GraalVM. The other two green bubbles are shown at the top of the blue barrel.

You asked:

> 1. How can I get Oracle OpenJDK 11.0.11+9 directly from Oracle?

Apparently you want Oracle's non-commercial unsupported distribution built from the OpenJDK source code, and published under the GNU General Public License, version 2, with the Classpath Exception. If so, see the product page for [*Oracle OpenJDK*](https://jdk.java.net/) (not to be confused with *Oracle JDK*/*Oracle Java SE*.)

This page, [*Java Platform, Standard Edition 11 Reference Implementations*](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11), provides links for current releases of such Java 11 implementations for Linux and for Windows. The current release is for build 11+28. If you really want the older outdate `11.0.11+9` release, you will need to go spelunking through their archives. I recommend sticking with the latest build instead.

> 2. Does the version available at Adoptium have any differences to Oracle OpenJDK 11.0.11+9 from Oracle?

No. I quoted above Oracle saying explicitly, no differences. *Oracle OpenJDK* is built directly from the OpenJDK source code. As are the releases from *Adoptium* at the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation), formerly known as *AdoptOpenJDK*. And, as are releases from some other vendors.

Oracle has been working to disabuse you and others of the incorrect notion that somehow there is "real" Java from Oracle and "fake" Java from others. Nearly all the implementations you can get from any of several vendors are all built largely or entirely from the OpenJDK codebase. There are two exceptions:

- Like Oracle, some vendors such as Azul Systems, Red Hat, and others reserve the right to distribute urgent fixes to their paying customers faster than would happen going through the OpenJDK process.
- A few products are specialized, to meet niche needs not addressed by the OpenJDK design goals. For example, AOT-compilation in GraalVM, and addressing very large amounts of memory with exceptional garbage-collection in *Azul Platform Prime* (formerly Zing) by Azul Systems.

> 3. If getting what I'm looking for is not possible, then where does Adoptium get what they provide? Do they just build their builds from source?

Adoptium provides binaries & installers built from the source code of OpenJDK.

| Project | Source code | Binaries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OpenJDK | ✅ | ❌ |
| Adoptium | ❌ | ✅ |

Adoptium also builds a suite of tests to verify their builds’ compliance with the Java specs. And Adoptium has made open-source projects of their tests and tooling.

Some vendors adapt their own distributions from the work of Adoptium. Indeed, the Adoptium project itself is a collaborative effort by several of the seemingly-competing vendors (along with other folks).

> 4. If what I'm looking for is not possible, why is it not possible? Is it due to Oracle's licensing decisions? Does the update I'm looking for count as a paid support patch? If so, I thought Oracle didn't release those updates to OpenJDK?

If I understand you correctly, what you want *is* possible, in the *Oracle OpenJDK* open-source GPL2-CPE product, not to be confused for the *Oracle JDK* commercial product. See your “1.” item a few paragraphs higher in this Answer.

I strongly suggest your read [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244), a white paper written by pillars of the Java community.

Comment: Thank you for being so clear and answering my points. I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: I'm an Oracle employee, but I'm speaking for myself here: The Java 11 reference implementation you link to is an outdated version of Java 11 from November 2018. Those builds are _not_ for production use, as the page says: `"These binaries are for reference use only!"`. Oracle does not provide up to date builds of Java 11 under the GPLv2-CPE license, only proprietary builds under the OTN license as part of their LTS support for Java 11, where you have to pay for commercial use (found here https://www.oracle.com/uk/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html).

Comment: @JornVernee Thank you for the correction; I’ll soon update the Answer. Given that Java 11 is an [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version, I am surprised to hear that Oracle is not keeping current with their *Oracle OpenJDK* product. Can you point me to official policy on what versions of Java will be supported by ongoing releases of *Oracle OpenJDK*?