# How to check whether JVM installed on my machine can do JIT optimisation

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

This is the output of `java -version` command on my machine

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

I have 2 queries here

1 ) Everytime i am reading about JIT , keyword Hotspot comes around , as my VM is not Hotspot, i get confused what execution strategy is being used by my JVM here , is it interpreter and C1 and C2, or only interpreter  ?

2 ) Let's say i am hosting a tomcat server with java spring backend , so every request that comes , will get interpreted , essentially the 1st request that comes may go through slightly different execution than say the 1000th request , if we assume JIT is in picture?

Comment: For most practical concerns, this OpenJDK JVM is the same as the HotSpot JVM. See [OpenJDK vs Java HotspotVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44335605/2711488)

Comment: Run any Java program with the -XX:+PrintCompilation option and you'll see all the JIT activity being printed.

Comment: @Holger please correct me if i am wrong, so Open-JDK8 has now both JRockit and Hotspot combined and only differs from Oracle JVM in proprietary features like Flight Recorder and Mission Control