# Official OpenJDK 11.0.4 binaries download

Tags: java, download, binaries

The latest long term release of OpenJDK is 11.0.4 https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDKUpdates/JDK11u but I cannot find an official download site for it similar to the OpenJDK site https://jdk.java.net/12/

Are the OpenJDK 11.0.4 binaries for Windows, Mac and Linux available for download from an official source?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the latest 11.0.4 release in the `Releases` section of that page.

The binaries are available [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-upstream-binaries/releases/tag/jdk-11.0.4%2B11).

Comment: There is no Mac release there and it doesn't look like an official source

Comment: This is indeed an official source - taken from the `Releases` section from the page you linked under `Binaries`, which leads you to the release tag of the official upstream binaries repository. As for the Mac release I can't give you more information.

Comment: It also says here https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-upstream-binaries "Not to be confused with the official AdoptOpenJDK binaries openjdk11-binaries."

Comment: And what's the point of releasing an "official release" without providing a binary for Mac which is one of the official platforms.

Comment: The aforementioned repository is the repository for nightly and release builds - you're looking for the LTS release, which is located inside my link.

Another provider for binaries is azul - they have a MacOS binary published - https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&version=java-11-lts&os=macos&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk

Comment: I found this already but I don't understand why I need to download an official OpenJDK LTS release from a 3rd party like Azul ... What if there is a backdoor or virus in this release? I want to download Open JDK releases from an official Open JDK location.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the open jdk (8, 11, 13) versions with different variant from the below link:

https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot

You can find the difference between hotspot and openj9 from the below link:

[Difference between JVM and HotSpot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568253/difference-between-jvm-and-hotspot)