# Isn't AdoptOpenJDK using (the JVM of) OpenJDK?

Tags: java, jvm, adoptopenjdk

The AdoptOpenJDK project seems to ship JDKs bundled with HotSpot JVM (as one possible option). But what is its relationship with OpenJDK then?

---

I understand [the word OpenJDK can be ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431765/2160440). Here I am referring to (quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK))

> a free and open-source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE).

which I think already contains a JVM.

Comment: "_AdoptOpenJDK uses infrastructure, build and test scripts to produce prebuilt binaries from OpenJDK™ class libraries and a choice of either the OpenJDK HotSpot or Eclipse OpenJ9 VM_" – https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about programming, but rather, a question about third-party projects and their relationship to each other.

Comment: Well, different JVM implementations still need to follow the spec so you can choose any that fits your needs. The difference often lies in implementation details like how the JIT compiler or garbage collectors operate or different runtime options. Any JVM that passes the TCK verification should be able to run any Java program so you're free to choose what fits your needs or platform best - and AdoptOpenJDK just provides that choice.

Comment: @Slaw That all makes sense now. I thought HotSpot refers to the Oracle HotSpot JVM exclusively. I would be happy to mark this post as accepted if you can summarize your comment in an answer. Besides, would you mind elaborate on which part of OpenJDK code is used (I guess primarily javac and rt.jar?) when the OpenJ9 JVM is chosen?

Comment: @RealSkeptic what about the linked question in the post? Also the sample question "Do Swift-based applications work on OS X 10.9/iOS 7 and lower?" at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I am not too happy about the linked question, but apparently, it provides value for programming because it asks for comparison between two environment, the answers to which may well be relevant for *development* of code. However, the relation of two projects is a legal question that has little to bear on programming.

Comment: Related: [*Difference between JVM and HotSpot?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16568253/642706) and [*Differences between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22358071/642706).

Comment: Also related: [*Difference between OpenJDK and AdoptOpenJDK*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52431764/642706).

Comment: Update: *AdoptOpenJDK* has changed its name to *Adoptium*, as part of its [move to the Eclipse Foundation](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2020/06/adoptopenjdk-to-join-the-eclipse-foundation/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** *AdoptOpenJDK* has changed its name to *Adoptium*, as part of its [move to the Eclipse Foundation](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2020/06/adoptopenjdk-to-join-the-eclipse-foundation/).

---

OpenJDK provides complete source code for a full implementation of the [Java Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)) as defined in the [Java Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), [JSR](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/overview)s, and [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0)s. An implementation of the Java platform includes many things, among them:

- A [Java programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) compiler to create `.class` [Java bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) files from your `.java` source code files.
- A [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) that can, at runtime, interpret and/or compile those Java bytecode files, turning them into executable code that can run on the host computer’s cores using the [native instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) of that [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit).
- A runtime environment that connects Java apps with the host machine’s resources such as [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and [network facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network).
- A required set of Java class libraries (*java.util*, *java.time*, etc.).

An implementation of Java has the option of providing a [Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler/optimizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) as part of the JVM. The OpenJDK project includes source code for the [HotSpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) JIT.

People providing builds or installers for the Java Platform are free to use HotSpot or to choose another JIT compiler technology. [OpenJ9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) in one such alternative JIT, developed at IBM, now open-sourced through the Eclipse Foundation, and provided free-of-charge. In the past, another alternative JIT was [JRockit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit), owned by Oracle. Parts of JRockit have been merged into the current version of HotSpot.

[image: Diagram showing the evolution of JIT options in the JVM, with older HotSpot merging with JRockit to produce modern OpenJDK HotSpot, and the alternative J9 being open-sourced as OpenJ9.]

The [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) project offers you choice of either the *HotSpot* engine provided by Oracle via the OpenJDK project or the alternative *OpenJ9* engine provided by the Eclipse Foundation.

With either choice you get the same class libraries from OpenJDK codebase, the same tools including [*Mission Control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Mission_Control) and [*Flight Recorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Flight_Recorder) from OpenJDK, and the same utilities from OpenJDK. Only the JIT/JVM is different whether you choose HotSpot or OpenJ9.

[image: Screenshot of download page at AdoptOpenJDK offering you a choice either HotSpot JIT or OpenJ9 JIT.]

AdoptOpenJDK is only one of several vendors providing distributions of Java techonology as binaries/installers. Most of these are based mostly, if not entirely, on the OpenJDK project’s source code releases. Here is a flowchart showing you the various vendors.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

And here is a list of possible motivations to consider in selecting a vendor.

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer. So AdopOpenJDK may actually adopt no only (the library) part of OpenJDK, but (the JVM) part of OpenJ9. Is that correct?

Comment: @wlnirvana Yes, currently AdoptOpenJDK offers builds with the libraries of OpenJDK and your choice of JVM, either HotSpot from OpenJDK or OpenJ9 from Eclipse.