# Is there a way to break down a 1-D List<Model> into a 2D array?

Tags: c#, wpf

Since C# is so flexible (due in part to its *interpreted* nature) I was wondering whether the following feature is readily available. Otherwise I will just roll my own.

I have a `List<MyModel>` which would be much easier/convenient to traverse with a nested loop:

```
for (col = 1 to lastCol)
    for (row = 1 to lastRow)
        scrutinize(row, col);
```

Addition: Perhaps I should use `foreach` across the columns?

Comment: You may need to give more information on MyModel.

Comment: 1) C# is *not* an interpreted language. 2) The code you have posted is *not* C#.

Comment: What do you mean by traversing a `List<T>` with a nested loop? Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve? Please do include code of your current solution.

Comment: Let's say that the properties are the TV manufacturers: and the rows the number of units sold each year. In need `for manufacturer = apple to zenith`

Comment: **[XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to do?** Post some additional code to clarify what is needed.

Comment: I need to refer to each cell with an [x,y] pair. Let's say that I want to add all the sales of all the manufacturers. I am guessing that I should use `foreach`

Comment: @OndrejTucny: "C# is not an interpreted language." Microsoft is working on a project to provide **compiled C#**

Comment: Really unclear; **why** do you “need to refer to each cell with an [x,y] pair”? If you are starting with a list, what do x and y represent?

Comment: @TravisBanger You should rather read something about the terms *interpreted* and *interpreter*, *compiler*, *JIT*, etc. before making such claims. Otherwise you may sound funny.

Comment: @OndrejTucny is right. [C# is compiled into IL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8837367/643085)

Comment: @TravisBanger One more thing: Please **do not** repeat tags in question titles, which is a general consensus on Stack Overflow. Almost all your questions are spoiled like that.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your title question, you can break down one dimensional list into 2D array by using LINQ. For simple list of integers:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var array =
list.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i})
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 4, x => x.Value, (key,values) => values.ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

and then you can access `list` elements by using two dimensional `array`.

Comment: Does this create a real 2D array or is it an array of arrays (jagged array)?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, it creates jagged array but for OP it seems to not make a difference

Comment: The problem with that code above is that my model is cast in stone. I cannot change it to a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @TravisBanger, array is of type `[][]`, there is no need to use `Dictionary`

Comment: After experimenting with MSVS I think I found a solution: my model needs to be IEnumerable.

Comment: @TravisBanger `my model needs to be IEnumerable` sounds bad enough for me to insist in clarification.

Comment: @HighCore Insist? Just how do you expect to enforce that?

Comment: @blam maybe I used the wrong term? `insist` in spanish would be to ask/say the same thing over and over.

Comment: @HighCore Your English is very good if it is a second language.  Insist is like an order or command.  Request is more polite.  For sure u know MVVM.